# Difference between regular and transitive action in terms of stabilizers in a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, group-actions

A group action on a set is said to be transitive if it has only one orbit. Now, a group action on the same set is said to be regular if all the stabilizers of the elements of the set are trivial.

My doubt is, if there is only one orbit, then, by orbit-stabilizer, all stabilizers must be trivial right? What am I missing here? Any hints? Thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add on to the answer by MathFail, the reason this doesn't contradict orbit stabilizer is that orbit-stabilizer (for a finite group) tells us that $|G_x| \cdot |G \cdot x| = |G|$. If our group acts transitively on a set $X$, it tells us that $|G \cdot x| = |X|$, and so, plugging that into orbit-stabilizer gives that $|X| \cdot |G_x| = |G|$. If $|X|$ is smaller than $|G|$, we can have $|G_x| > 1$! Note, however, that this implies for a finite group $G$ acting on a set $X$ with $|G| = |X|$, we have that the action is regular iff it is transitive.

With this in mind, is it possible to come up with an example of a group action that is regular but not transitive?

Comment: Actually, regular action is stronger than transitivity right? I thought that regular implies transitive. Could you post an example?

Comment: Got it! Just make a group of lower cardinality act on a set with making the identity of group the only element fixing the elements. Then, the action is regular, but not transitive, right?

Comment: Yeah -- you can write this down explicitly by having $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ act on the set $\{1, 2, 3, 4\}$. Make $0$ fix everything, and make $1$ correspond to the map $1 \mapsto 3, 2 \mapsto 4, 3 \mapsto 1, 4 \mapsto 2$. The stabilizer of each element is trivial, and this is a group action. 

Note that your definition of regular is actually nonstandard --https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Regular_group_action the definition you have seems to correspond to what the literature calls semiregular. The normal definition of regular is semiregular and transitive.

Comment: But then, this implies that for a regular action, the cardinality of the group must equal that of the set. Is this true? What about Cayley graphs having their automorphism group much larger in cardinality than the base group of the cayley graph

Comment: It's possible that graph theorists use a different definition of regular action than group theorists; I should say that it's different from what I've seen in the group theory I've done. I was mostly mentioning it because you might see theorems that say "regular implies transitive", but that only applies to the definition I linked, not the one you're working with.

Answer (score 4):

No, it is false. Let $G=\langle g\rangle$ and $|G|=4$, and set $X=\{a, b\}$. Define

$$ea=a, eb=b, ga=b, gb=a$$

hence $G$ is transitively acting on $X$, but the stablizer

$$G_a=\{e, g^2\}=G_b$$

is non-trivial.

Answer (score 3):

> if there is only one orbit, then, by orbit-stabilizer, all stabilizers must be trivial right?

Not really. Rather, the orbit-stabilizer tells you that all the stabilizers have order $\frac{|G|}{|X|}$, which is not necessarily equal to $1$.